# How do I get my code to skip a user input using a scanner with an if statement,

Tags: java, equation

I am using a scanner to ask for user input (pressure, volume, temp, moles) but I am solving for two different equations in my IF statement. I am trying to get it to only ask for only needed variables instead of all of them. For instance, solving for Moles, I only need pressure, Gas, Temp, and Volume. I do not need to ask the user for "number of moles" since that is what I am trying to solve for. can someone assist? Thanks,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author 261141
 */
public class IdealGasLaw1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      String answer;

      System.out.println("What do you want to solve for?");   
      answer = s.nextLine();


      System.out.print("Pressure? (in Torr) ");
      double pressure = in.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("Volume? (in liters) ");
      double volume = in.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("Temp ? (in Kelvin) ");
      double temp = in.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("Moles? ");
      double moles = in.nextDouble();

      double gas = 62;

      double PresAns = (pressure)*(volume)/gas * (temp+273);
      double MoleAns = (pressure)*(moles);

      if (answer.equals("Moles" )) { 
          System.out.println("Moles =" +MoleAns +" moles");            
      } 
      else 
          System.out.println("Pressure =: "+PresAns +" Torr");
    }   
}
```

Comment: the same way you did in your `System.out.println(`. If the issue is the variable declaration, see what you did for `answer`

Comment: As a side note, do you really need two scanners?

Answer (score 0):

Use `answer` to decide if moles is needed.  For example:

```
double moles = 0;
if (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Moles")) {   // note the use of the NOT symbol
  System.out.print("Moles? ");
  moles = in.nextDouble();
}
```

Also, `moles` is declared outside the `if` statement and must be initialized, otherwise the code won't compile.  Try similar for other input variables.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works for you. I have used an if clause to check what the user input is(Moles/Pressure). Based on that, the program asks the user for different inputs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author 261141
 */
public class IdealGasLaw1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      String answer;
      double gas = 62;
      System.out.println("What do you want to solve for?");   
      answer = s.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Pressure? (in Torr) ");
      double pressure = in.nextDouble();

      if(answer.equals("Moles")) {
          System.out.print("Moles? ");
          double moles = in.nextDouble();
          double MoleAns = (pressure)*(moles);
          System.out.println("Moles =" +MoleAns +" moles");            
      }
      else if(answer.equals("Pressure")) {

          System.out.print("Volume? (in liters) ");
          double volume = in.nextDouble();
          System.out.print("Temp ? (in Kelvin) ");
          double temp = in.nextDouble();
          double PresAns = (pressure)*(volume)/gas * (temp+273);
          System.out.println("Pressure =: "+PresAns +" Torr");
      }


    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. I was having an issue declaring a variable inside my If statement but all your feedback helped. I used Pravins if Clause  to solve it. (I needed to adjust my equation as well). But Thanks a bunch! and yes two scanners are not needed so I will clean that up. Cheers!